# why Ajax code not trigger on click or load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

Thanks for you all.

I am new in coding MVC, and I am trying to code a page that will create  and

as parent and child loop, using data from JSON (MenuHandler.ashx), the JSON data is tested and it's ok, but the Ajax was not working.

for your kind note: the Alert working before and after Ajax

this is my VIEW page:

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#testaj1").click(function () {

                alert ("test22")
                
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'MenuHandler.ashx',
                    method: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {

                        buildMenu($('#menu'), data)
                        $('#menu').menu();
                        
                       
                    }


                });
                alert("test33")
            });

            function buildMenu(parent, items) {
                $.each(items, function () {
                    var li = $('<li>' + this.Name + '</li>');


                    li.appendTo(parent);

                    if (this.List && this.List.length > 0) {


                        var ul = $('<ul></ul>');
                        ul.appendTo(li);
                        buildMenu(ul, this.List);


                    }

                })

            }

        })
       
        

    </script>
```

```css
 <link href="~/Content/MyCSS/MyCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

```html
@model IEnumerable<pedigree.Models.pedigree1>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
   
 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>




    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>

    <form>
        <button id="testaj1" type="button" >test</button>

        <div class="tree">

            <ul id="menu">
            </ul>


        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: The idea of a snippet is to have runnable code that we can use to help us answer your question. Please update the snippet to something that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Since the alerts are working the click handler is also working. Add an `error:` handler to see if your request is successful. Even better, check the browser's dev console to see what response the server returns.

Comment: @phuzi thanks for your  replay, I am new in this site so I didn't how to use it in good way.

Comment: @Jasen Thanks, can you please advice me where I have to add it

Comment: @Jasen I add error handler, and it back with 404 message!

Comment: the error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () MenuHandler.ashx, this page is in side the same view folder now.

Comment: Then you'll need to determine the correct URL to reach your server side page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common reason is the controller that you are pointing, maybe the controler uri is not correct, also be sure that your controller is returning a JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your help, actually there are no controller, I use MenuHandler.ashx for Josn  data, and when I check the results I found that : the error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () MenuHandler.ashx, this file is in the main root of my project, even when I move it to the same folder of the view page it was not working

Comment: I'm glad to see that your project is now running properly :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone as Alejandro Coronado said, the issue was in the handler.ashx file, I don’t now why wasn’t worked, but when I use instead  json result action
The Ajax worked and the results came according to my expectations

Thanks everyone